# What is the easiest way to test if an enum-based variable is *not* equal to a specific case with an associated value?

Tags: swift, enums, associated-value

We have the following enum and variable

```
enum DisplayState{
    case loading
    case loaded(ViewModel)
    case noResults
    case error
}

var displayState:DisplayState = .loading
```

We want to test if we're in any state other than `loaded`.

Since there is an associated value, this of course doesn't work...

```
if displayState != .loaded {
    // Do something
}
```

But I'm hoping to find something else besides either of these...

```
switch displayState{
    case .loaded: break
    default: // Do something
}
```

or

```
if case .loaded = displayState {} else {
    // Do something
}
```

So what's the simplest way to test for this case?

Comment: You're a source of consistently good questions. This one's interesting! I typically make helper computed vars, like `isLoading`, `isLoaded`, `hasNoResults`, `isErrored`, so I would use one of those.

Comment: Thanks for the kudos!  Swift is such a great language, which is why this surprised me that it has to be so convoluted for these simple tests where you don't care what the value is. I feel I should be able to test against a value and just ignore its type though.  I may have to visit Swift Evolution to see if there was rationale behind not doing that. I mean you can pattern-match against it while ignoring the associated values, so why not overload the equality to do the same?

Comment: Yeah, I wish there was a sort of "metaenum" made for enums with associated values, which lets you talk about the cases without particular regard for the associated values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try that:

```
enum DisplayState {
    case loading
    case loaded(ViewModel)
    case noResults
    case error

    var isLoaded: Bool {
        switch self {
        case .loaded:
            return true
        default:
            return false
        }
    }
}

var displayState: DisplayState = .loading

if displayState.isLoaded {
    // code
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach. It's a shame you have to decorate your enums like this.  I wonder why the Swift team didn't just allow the simple != check. I mean you can pattern match against it!  But this is a good work-around.  Lemme leave it open a bit longer to see if someone comes up with any alternatives. If not, I'll mark this as accepted.

Comment: @MarqueIV I agree, however computed vars inside your enum is probably your best bet.